# Spring-ws: how to decompress incoming request

Tags: request, compression, interceptor, spring-ws

Jersey and Apache Cxf have nice feautres with it:
GzipInOutInterceptors or similar, which could compress incoming-outgoing requests.
Does spring-ws have something like that?
I only found that it compress outgoing requests.

Answer (score 0):

Spring-WS is also designed to support decompressing incoming messages, and this doesn't require any additional configuration, as long as the messages have the expected `Content-Encoding: gzip` header. The code that does this can be found in [`AbstractHttpSenderConnection`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/xref/org/springframework/ws/transport/http/AbstractHttpSenderConnection.html).